# Что за слово "скалдырничество"?

Tags: этимология

Услышал такое слово - "скалдырничество" в значении "жадность". Но даже представить себе не могу, откуда оно могло появиться в русском языке. Подскажите, пожалуйста, интересно же!))
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фасмер говорит, что все существующие этимологии недостоверны
http://onlineslovari.com/etimologicheskiy_slovar_russkogo_yazyika_maksa_fasmera/page/skaldyira.12054

скалды́ра, сколды́ра"-  скряга, попрошайка" (Даль),  – то же (см.), скалды́рник "ростовщик, скупердяй - человек, который из всего извлечёт выгоду" (Гоголь), также сквалды́ра (Преобр.).

Это диалектное слово, возможно, связано с иностранным заимствованием.Диалектные слова трудно отследить, часто это искажённые иностранные. Кто-то допускает даже от "скальды"-поэты, потому что скальды воспевали и врагов ради выгоды.А в корне этого слова - есть значение "донос", презрительное отношение к скальдам было как к людям, готовым ради выгоды на всё,  у Гоголя так называет Плюшкина  Ноздрёв.

Comment: "Ну, послушай, чтоб доказать тебе, что я вовсе не какой-нибудь скалдырник, я не возьму за них ничего. Купи у меня жеребца, я тебе дам их в придачу". (*Ноздрёв*)

Answer (score 2):

У слова *скалдырник* много синонимов и похожих по происхождению слов :

> **скалдырник**
> скупердяй, жила, жмот, скопидом, сквалыжник, скаредник, скряжник, скундыжник, скряга, жадюга, скупец, сквалыга, скупой, скаред, скважина, копеечник, жадина, выжига, сквалдырник, скалдыра
> Словарь русских синонимов.

Скважина - от *сквозной, насквозь*, довольно понятно значение прозвища. Что-то вроде *продувной бестии*.
Скалдыра и сквалдырник содержат в себе как бы намек на тот же самый смысл - "с дырками, худой" (??)
Сквалыга (или скалвыга) напоминают о старинном названии чаши весов : **скалва**. Вполне вероятно, что пройдоху-весовщика могли назвать сквалыжником, если он регулярно обманывал своих клиентов при помощи нехитрых трюков с весами. Обман и обвес покупателей знаком всем и каждому, во все времена.
Версии о *скалдыре и сквалыге* предположительны, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Я тут глянул "Полный церковно-славянский словарь" магистра Григория Дьяченко , страницу 603 - интернет-ссылка [link text](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0603.htm) . Там есть  " **Скалвы , скалы = весовыя чашки или то же , что нынешние весы , санскр. skhal - колебаться . ...**"  , и есть "**Скалочный = слово греч. , происходящее от глагола  < ... >   рою , гребу , очищаю , напр. скалочный пепел .**" Можно предположить что тут смысловая связь с **торгашеской меркантильностью** , то есть , как "**весовщик**" , либо типа , как "**выгребать дочиста**" , ну в том же смысле , что "*обобрать до нитки*" , -  **скалдырь** это тот , кто **всё выгребает себе** . *Примечание : я затрудняюсь воспроизвести греческое слово , и поэтому на его месте поместил "скобочки" с точками , - смотрите его по ссылке*  .

Answer (score 0):

Словарь Дайхеса
Скалдырник - скалу дырит, а ежли скалу скребёт - то скряга, ежли скряга костёр на скале палит - выжига, а когда наварит мало яец - то скупец, коли в скале вену золотую отхватит - то жила, а рядом избушку сварганит - скопидом... 
Так что, пилите, Шура, пилите!

Подарок, тебе, родной мой.
http://enc-dic.com/fasmer/eA/

Только, чур, листы не вырывать.